# Using custom fonts in CSS

Tags: css

I have been wanting to add custom fonts to my website using css.I have tried downloading from google fonts but it is  not working.any other way of adding these fonts?

Comment: Post some code so we can see why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want add google font. i think you don't need to download. Go to google font site https://www.google.com/fonts choose you font and click on quick use button

Then you need to copy the link href code into head in your html file and add the font name in css file

Answer (score 0):

first go to https://www.google.com/fonts , select your font and import it like this in your style.css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
```

now you can use with , for example

```
div p { font-family : 'Open Sans' , Sans-serif }
```